# MySQL queries, selecting field from one of many databases

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I have a `remarks` table which can be linked to any number of other items in a system, in the case of this example we'll use `bookings`, `enquiries` and `referrals`.

Thus in the `remarks` table we have columns

```
remark_id | datetime    | text | booking_id | enquiry_id | referral_id
1         | 2014-06-28  | abc  | 0          | 8          | 0
2         | 2014-06-27  | def  | 3          | 0          | 0
2         | 2014-05-31  | ghi  | 0          | 0          | 10
```

Etc...

Each of the *item* tables will have a field called `name`. Thus when I want to select a remark the likelihood is I'll need this name.

I'd like to achieve this with a single query, getting a 2d array as follows:

```
['remark_id'=>1, 'datetime'=>'2014-06-28', 'text'=>'abc', 'name'=>'Harold']
```

However the query I'd expect to use would be

```
 SELECT r.remark_id,r.datetime,r.text
 ,b.name AS book,rr.name AS referral,e.name AS enquiry
 FROM remarks AS r
 LEFT JOIN bookings AS b ON b.book_id=r.book_id
 LEFT JOIN referrals AS rr ON rr.referral_id=r.referral_id
 LEFT JOIN enquiries AS e ON e.enquiry_id=r.enquiry_id
```

Leaving me with the output

```
['remark_id'=>1, 'datetime'=>'2014-06-28', 'text'=>'abc', 'book'=>'Harold', 'referral'=>'', 'enquiry'=>'']
```

And more processing to do before or during rendering it to a view.

Is there a way to write a query such that it would fill a field from the first `NOT NULL` string it encountered in one of the joined tables?

*Please only suggest using a different database system if you **know** that `MySQL` doesn't provide any way to do what I'm asking. If it's the case it can't be done there's no business sense in rewriting the system anyway, but I'd like to ask!*

Comment: also just noticed a possible typo - presume you meant rr.name in the select clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

1. use UNION:

   ```
   SELECT remark_id, datetime, text, name
   FROM remarks
   JOIN bookings ON (remarks.book_id = bookings.book_id)
   UNION 
   SELECT remark_id, datetime, text, name
   FROM remarks
   JOIN referrals ON (remarks.referral_id = referrals.referral_id)
   UNION
   SELECT remark_id, datetime, text, name
   FROM remarks
   JOIN enquiries ON (remarks.enquiry_id = enquiries.enquiry_id)</code>
   ```
2. use IFNULL (probably much slower):

   ```
   SELECT r.remark_id,r.datetime,r.text,
   IFNULL(b.name,IFNULL(rr.name,e.name)) AS name
   FROM remarks AS r
   LEFT JOIN bookings AS b ON b.book_id=r.book_id
   LEFT JOIN referrals AS rr ON rr.referral_id=r.referral_id
   LEFT JOIN enquiries AS e ON e.enquiry_id=r.enquiry_id</code>
   ```

Variant 2 is really much slower because of the `LEFT JOIN`s.

Also, generally I would not recommend using `0` as value for non-existent links, rather use `NULL`. This will allow MySQL to speed up the join.

Comment: That's a useful bit of advice on the foreign key - is that as simple as setting the INT() field to be NULL rather than 0 if left empty on INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this is with nested if statements:

```
if(b.name is not null, b.name, if(rr.name is not null, rr.name, e.name)) as name
```

one drawback is that this gives an implicit priority to books? not sure if that would be an issue.

perhaps the main drawback, though, is that this is kind of "magical" and has goofy syntax so it might be more clear to just handle those cases in the controller after all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite messy that you have multiple unused columns for each entry, unless I'm not understanding correctly. If you add more tables, you'd have to adjust each of the views so that it would filter out the new table.

I'd be tempted to redesign your structure so that each of the tables has a remarkgroup_id column, then add the following remark table

remark_id, remarkgroup_id, date, message

This would clean up the extra unused columns and allow you to use simple joining logic.

Comment: Wouldn't this still end up with each table being joined on, just that they're now joined by a consistently named column? E.g. `LEFT JOIN bookings AS b ON b.remarkgroup_id=r.remarkgroup_id`?

Comment: It's cleaner database design. In your example remark_id 1 has no interest in either bookings or referrals, and yet we still have references to them, which is what it seems your issue is.

I think you need to perform some normalization of your structure, to at least 3NF. You could simplify it further and just have a remark(text) column for each table, but I assumed you might want more than one remark for each entry.

It seems that you're wanting to produce a list of all remarks for whichever item they're put against. I'll come up with a query in the next comment because no more space!

Comment: `SELECT r.text,b.name,r.datetime FROM remark r INNER JOIN bookings b  ON r.remarkgroup_id=b.remarkgroup_id ORDER_BY r.datetime ASC`

Comment: and just have a query for each table that would return the required remarks. Note that I'm using Oracle SQL notation, not sure how different MySQL is but the theory is the same.

Comment: OK, I can see your reasoning with the single join approach. However I'd prefer to run one query in this instance, as we're unlikely to ever be returning more than 100 remarks. It's also unlikely that many more item tables will be added, and some times we have more than one ID set.